# how to allocate dynamic port and get details of that[JMX]

Tags: java, jmx

**Requirement:** I want to  run multiple process(with remote properties i.e.Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port ) that can be view remotely via JMX on another machine.

Initially Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=**9875** (picking from properties files) but it stricts me to run single process only.saving port information from the machine(where i am running process) in database for further use .

Then I used -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=**0** for dynamic port allocation to run multiple process.Now i can run multiple process but i am not able to get the port information so that i can save that information in database that will be used further for remote connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this trick to get dynamic port

`ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
   int jmxPort =  socket.getLocalPort();`

This will allocate a dynamic port and then pass it to as VM args **Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=jmxPort**

jmx port can be saved in database and can be used when need to make JMX connection.

Hope will be helpful.